# C# Server Stub from swagger yaml

Tags: swagger

I want to generate C# server tub from swagger yaml file. Can anybody help me? Is there any tool to generate it?

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to import your Swagger/OpenAPI spec into https://editor.swagger.io and in the top menu bar click on "Generate Server" and then select "Aspnet5" or "Nancyfx"

Or you can install [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) locally. Here is a good starting point:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.